# X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN blocking iframe on my domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox, x-frame-options

i'm using http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox to display the content of an url in a lightbox.
after implementation, the colorbox did'nt showed anything.

Later, i noticed the following error in chrome logs:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

so after documenting i added the following line to the root .htaccess of the website :

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

to allow iframe embedding on my own domain.

But i still get the error, i'm newbie to x-frame, and i'm working on an existing application, so i thought the .htaccess solution would be nice, but can it be overrided by some code ? Notice that it's not in the server configuration.

Answer (score 19):

Try sending another X-Frame-Options header, add

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); ?>
```

to the top of your page.
It should disable the SAMEORIGIN command.

Comment: i tested it without success, then i gave up and made my popin inline >.< But it's still weird, SAMEORIGIN should allow me to embed iframe in my domain.

Comment: After trying a whole bunch of other "fixes" to get Wordpress to render in an iFrame, this FINALLY was teh one that made it work for me!

Comment: Hi, i try this but i dont have success, cau you tell me where i need put this in my wordpress site? thanks

Comment: A much more secure option is `<?php header("X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com/"); ?>`, where `https://example.com` is the site you want to allow to display the page in an iframe. [(Documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 6):

According to the moz dev pages. Here is the definition of the

> ***SAMEORIGIN***
>   The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the
>   page itself.

It mean that only if you are including some page from your site would be shown.
Let suppose

1. you have a website on http://foo.com and you want something to show in iframe from the http://foo.com/sec_page it would show up in iframe
2. but if you embed the same iframe(http://foo.com/sec_page) to load in http://bar.com then it would not display anything.  As the origin would be changed.

You can read the [full note here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the header from the response you get:

**header_remove("X-Frame-Options");**

Answer (score 2):

I've added this in `httpd.conf`:

```
 Header unset X-Frame-Options
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set XFrame Options to DENY or Sameorigin. Else it may help in crafting phishing attacks or Frame injections if your site is vulnerable to XSS attack.