# PHP Target iframe and give it a ?cat

Tags: php, jquery, html, email, iframe

I'm working with a client who's forced to use a widget based web builder to manage their web content.

They're trying to include product images for consumers. Basically, they send an email with a product overview that comes with pictures. Seeing how we can't place a working image gallery in the email we decided to use php to build a gallery hosted on another site that swaps the images out via ?cat.

The site itself works fine. iFrameing it isn't working though.  Is there a way to target the iframe on the page to adjust the content accordingly?

Just to sum it up:

Email contains a url that takes the user to a web page with an iframe-d in image gallery that changes what images are displayed depending on the cat written in the emailed url.

note: User doesn't see gallery in the email but on a web page they are directed to from a link in the email.

Comment: you're trying to embed the remote site in the email? unless the user allows their mail client to fetch external resources, that won't work at all.

Comment: Gallery is not in email, but its on a external url that is included in email?

Comment: Yes, the url in the email takes the user to the business' website. Since I can't bulild the gallery using their web builder platform the gallery is hosted on another site and is displayed on the businesses page via iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because of X-Frame-Options, you Gallery site need to tell browser that its allowed to add contents. 
In php you can it to header using

The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: DENY'); ?>
```

The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN'); ?>
```

The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.iframe_webite'); ?>
```

[According to firefox website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Some more help on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182768/x-frame-options-sameorigin-blocking-iframe-on-my-domain)

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   ,  or  . Sites can use this to avoid
>   clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded
>   into other sites.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?